# Can't run Fe language on M2 MacOS Ventura: bad CPU type in executable

Tags: compiler

I tried installing [Fe](https://fe-lang.org/) lang on M2 MacOS Ventura through Homebrew and by downloading the executable but both installation options ended up with me seeing the following error.

> zsh: bad CPU type in executable: fe

The following output is from Homebrew.

> ferit@mba ~ % brew install fe
> ==> Downloading https://formulae.brew.sh/api/formula.jws.json
> ################################################################################################################# 100.0%
> ==> Downloading https://formulae.brew.sh/api/cask.jws.json
> ################################################################################################################# 100.0%
> ==> Fetching fe-lang/tap/fe
> ==> Downloading https://github.com/ethereum/fe/releases/download/v0.26.0/fe_mac
> Already downloaded: /Users/ferit/Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads/955dc269fece2b4f6db697546ef9614b43382239cdc0a351414449104a3927a5--fe_mac
> ==> Installing fe from fe-lang/tap
>   /opt/homebrew/Cellar/fe/0.26.0: 3 files, 22.0MB, built in 2 seconds
> ==> Running `brew cleanup fe`...
> Disable this behaviour by setting HOMEBREW_NO_INSTALL_CLEANUP.
> Hide these hints with HOMEBREW_NO_ENV_HINTS (see `man brew`).
> ferit@mba ~ %

Any ideas about what's happening here? Perhaps M2 chips are unsupported?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installing Rosetta 2, Apple's x86-to-ARM translation layer, solved the problem.

The following command installs Rosetta.

```
/usr/sbin/softwareupdate --install-rosetta --agree-to-license
```